# window.googleapis is undefined

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

I am trying to add a G+ +1 button on my web page. I am following the steps provided on [Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/), but I get the following error **window.googleapis is undefined**. The same error appears even on [Google developers page](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/) (viewed in Firebug).

Why does this error appear?
And how can it be solved?

Comment: I don't see this problem in FF 18.02 or in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce the bug on Firefox 18.0.2 + Firebug 1.11.1, though as I said before not on Firefox 19.0 (with the same profile).
So obviously this was fixed in Firefox 19.0. If someone still sees that issue with that Firefox version, please comment at [issue 6280](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6280).

Comment: Yes, the error has disappeared in Firefox 19.0. Thank you team.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this error will appear only if the firebug is opened. Close firebug and refresh the page

Comment: Thanks, but I hope there is a better solution.